# How to create Plain Old Java Object for Database (RESTful service design)?

Tags: xml, jaxb, mapping, javabeans, pojo

I would like to generate POJO, XML for a given database.

Database: (**contents** is the table name)

[image]

Interested in knowing how **POJO** will look like and corresponding **XML** for the same.

For instance (xml look like this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<contents>
  <param1>x</param1>
  <param2>y</param2>
  <param3>2</param3>
</contents>
```

& corresponding POJO

```
public class Contents
{
    @XmlElement
    String param1;

    @XmlElement
    String param2;

    @XmlElement
    String param3;

    public String getparam1()
    {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1( String param1 )
    {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getparam2()
    {
        return param2;
    }

    public void setParam2( String param2 )
    {
        this.param2= param2;
    }

    public String getparam3()
    {
        return param3;
    }

    public void setParam3( String param3)
    {
        this.param3= param3;
    }

}
```

So if i want to add multiple ROWS ( 2nd and 3rd row ) in my XML how does my **POJO** and **XML** will look ?

assuming (xml should be)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<contents>
 <content>
   <param1>x</param1>
   <param2>y</param2>
   <param3>2</param3>
 </content>
 <content>
   <param1>a</param1>
   <param2>b</param2>
   <param3>1</param3>
 </content>
</contents>
```

Comment: I hate to be tonight's smart Alec, but your POJO and XML could look like many different things. What do you need them to look like ?

Comment: @PatriceM. edited my question with more details and what exactly i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="contents")
public class ContentsWrapper {

    public Collection<Contents> getContents() {
        if (contents == null) {
            contents = new ArrayList<Contents>();
        }
        return contents;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="content")
    private Collection<Contents> contents;
}
```